# Pass variable as attribute to XML body

Tags: scala, gatling

I am creating a Gatling load test in Scala and I wish to create a HTTP POST request with attribute.

```
 val getServiceCall = http("get service call")
.post("/MyService")
.headers(header)
.body(ElFileBody("templates/GetServiceCallRqTemplate.xml"))
.check(status.is(200))
```

And this is a snippet from my xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <pus:GetServiceCallRq>
        <com:header>
            <com:type>pus:GetServiceCallRq</com:type>
            <com:timestamp>timestamp</com:timestamp>
            <com:source>source</com:source>
            <com:destination>destination</com:destination>
            <com:serverNode>serverNode</com:serverNode>
        </com:header>
        <pus:body>
            <pus:reference>${reference}</pus:reference>
            ....
```

I would like to pass the `${reference}` attribute from a variable creating within my code - and not from a csv file.

How is it possible to pass it as a request param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a feeder (csv file) is not the only way to get a value into a session parameter.

you could also set the value manually via a session action

```
exec(session => session.set("reference", "ref0001"))
```

or via a check on an earlier request (whatever is in the 'ref' key in the response gets saved to the ${reference} variable

```
exec(
  http("setupReq")
  .get("someURL")
  .check(
    jsonPath("$.ref").saveAs("reference")
  )
)
```

or even by creating your own custom feeder - for example, if you just wanted to generate random references

```
//somewhere at the top of your scala class
private val refs = Iterator.continually(
  Map("reference" -> (Random.alphanumeric take 10 mkString).toUpperCase())
)

//then later in your scenario...
.feed(refs) //will put a new random string into ${reference}
//then make your "get service call" request
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your last advise helped me to get what I wanted.

Comment: if I do not want to insert a random number, but the values of a map, than how can I iterate through this map to put in every loop another value as parameter? Thank you!